# Unable to modify or reproduce a ragged numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

** For convenience, I prepared a [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oX0cOIgsGNjnW8u3lqkrkQqvcanMMMgn?usp=sharing) which downloads [gt.mat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Oq7AWzOb_pVJkJv69FewXynZaIBymt52/view?usp=sharing) and [sample_images.tar.gz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CyJ8VFfvsVu9jtRIgbc6GX3UsieUvS-S/view?usp=sharing) files needed to reproduce the problem.

I'm trying to reproduce examples from a text detection [repo](https://github.com/backtime92/CRAFT-Reimplementation) which depend on the following [dataset](https://github.com/ankush-me/SynthText). The current code is expecting 3 numpy arrays of `object` dtype, one of which has ragged sequences.

I read the file using:

```
>>> from scipy.io import loadmat

>>> labels = loadmat('gt.mat')
```

The resulting dict contains a few keys, 3 of which are interesting to the issue being addressed `charBB`, `imnames`, and `txt` which contain 858750 character bounding box coordinates, image paths, and words respectively.

```
>>> labels.keys()
dict_keys(['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'charBB', 'wordBB', 'imnames', 'txt'])
>>> {key: item.shape for (key, item) in labels.items() if isinstance(item, np.ndarray)}
{'charBB': (1, 858750),
 'wordBB': (1, 858750),
 'imnames': (1, 858750),
 'txt': (1, 858750)}
>>> labels['charBB'][0].shape
(858750,)
>>> labels['charBB'][0][0].shape  # first word character bboxes
(2, 4, 54)
>>> labels['charBB'][0][1].shape  # second word (different shape than the first's)
(2, 4, 60)
```

Let's say I need to select 100 images, download them and use them to run some examples locally, I'll have to extract the corresponding 100 items from each of the 3 arrays and discard the rest, which I do using:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import loadmat
from pathlib import Path


def load_synth_data(data_dir, labels_file, keys):
    char_boxes, words, image_paths = [], [], []
    labels = {
        key: np.squeeze(value) if isinstance(value, np.ndarray) else value
        for (key, value) in loadmat(labels_file).items()
    }
    total = labels['charBB'].shape[0]
    for i, (image_char_boxes, image_words, image_path) in enumerate(
        zip(*(labels[key] for key in keys)), 1
    ):
        found = len(char_boxes)
        display = [
            f'Loading {i}/{total}',
            f'{np.around((i / total) * 100, 2)}%',
            f'found: {found}',
            f'{np.around((found / total) * 100, 2)}%',
        ]
        print(f"\r{' | '.join(display)}", end='')
        if (image_path := (Path(data_dir) / image_path.item())).exists():
            char_boxes.append(image_char_boxes)
            words.append(image_words)
            image_paths.append(image_path.as_posix())
    print()
    return char_boxes, words, image_paths
```

Then I use it to select the existing images which are also provided in the notebook:

```
subset_boxes, subset_words, subset_paths = load_synth_data('sample_images/SynthText', 'gt.mat', ['charBB', 'txt', 'imnames'])
```

It works fine for `subset_words` and `subset_paths` (despite them having ragged shapes):

```
>>> np.array(subset_words, dtype='O')
array([array(['that the\n  had   \nIraq and\nwhat the'], dtype='<U35'),
       array(['the              ', '  beep  \nwhen the', 'and              '],
             dtype='<U17')                                                    ,
       array(['to test', 'the\nthe', 'far    '], dtype='<U7'), ...,
       array(['>In  ', 'of an'], dtype='<U5'),
       array(['the'], dtype='<U3'), array(['are', 'new'], dtype='<U3')],
      dtype=object)
```

And fails for `subset_boxes`

```
>>> np.array(subset_boxes, dtype='O')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3444, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-15-6275cb854275>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array(subset_boxes, 'O')
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,4,24) into shape (2,4)
```

torch repo code is expecting a numpy array similar to the one produced using `scipy.io.loadmat`, otherwise I get an incompatible batch shape problem which is outside the scope of my question. How can I create an array out of the selected examples, matching the expected shape `(858750,)`?

One workaround is to store the indices of the found items and use them to select the ones needed `labels['charBB'][[..., ...]]` which would solve the problem however, this won't help recreate the array from a list or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipping over most of your description, the last error is produced by an action like

```
In [407]: np.array([np.ones([2,4,3]),np.zeros([2,4,2])],'O')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-407-6868cb2349dc>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array([np.ones([2,4,3]),np.zeros([2,4,2])],'O')
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,4,3) into shape (2,4)
```

Creating an "ragged array" fails when the leading dimension(s) are the same.  `np.array(...)` tries to make a multidimensional array.  Failing that it, the fall back is object dtype array.  But a combination of dimensions like this takes it up a 'dead end', possibly because it makes the wrong "guess" as to the desired return shape.

The most reliable way to make an object dtype array from any mix of inputs is to initialize and assign:

```
In [408]: arr = np.empty(2,'O')
In [409]: arr
Out[409]: array([None, None], dtype=object)
In [410]: arr[:] = [np.ones([2,4,3]),np.zeros([2,4,2])]
```